# Moving more objects in Python tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, move

I'm making simple game - there're 8 ovals, they should be clickable and moveable. After click on an oval, the oval is following cursor. The target is to get the oval into rectangle, if you release mouse button in rectangle, the oval disappears. If you release mouse button outside rectangle, the oval should appear on it's initial position. I made this program and it works, but only for one oval. I need it works for all ovals. There's my code, any idea what to change, please?

```
import tkinter, random

class Desktop:

    array = [(50,50,70,70),(100,50,120,70),(150,50,170,70),(150,100,170,120),
            (150,150,170,170),(100,150,120,170),(50,150,70,170),(50,100,70,120)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=400,height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,250,300,350)
        for i in range(len(self.array)):
            self.__dict__[f'oval{i}'] = self.canvas.create_oval(self.array[i], fill='brown',tags='id')
        self.canvas.tag_bind('id','<B1-Motion>',self.move)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('id','<ButtonRelease-1>',self.release)

    def move(self, event):
        self.canvas.coords(self.oval0,event.x-10,event.y-10,event.x+10,event.y+10)

    def release(self, event):
        if event.x>100 and event.x<300 and event.y>250 and event.y<350:
            self.canvas.delete(self.oval0)
        else:
            self.canvas.coords(self.oval0,self.array[0])


d = Desktop()
```

Comment: the problem is that your `move `and `release` is hardcoded to `oval0` so on that oval moves. if you change that to `oval1` then next one would move.

Comment: you forgot `Tk()` and `mainloop()` - of course `Tkinter` can create `Tk()` automatically but it is better to do it manually so everyone can see it. And program without `mainloop()` will not work (it can work only in IDLE which uses Tkinter and runs `mainloop()` in background)

Comment: instead of  `self.__dict__[f'oval{i}']` you could use `self.ovals = dict()` and later `self.ovals[i] = ...` and then you can access every element using `self.oval[i]` and it will be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bind three methods

- `<ButtonPress-1>` to get ID of clicked item and assign to `self.selected`
- `<B1-Motion>` to move item using `self.selected`
- `<ButtonRelease-1>` to release or delete moved item using `self.selected`

Code

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Desktop:

    array = [(50,50,70,70),(100,50,120,70),(150,50,170,70),(150,100,170,120),
            (150,150,170,170),(100,150,120,170),(50,150,70,170),(50,100,70,120)]

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 250, 300, 350)

        # to keep all IDs and its start position
        self.ovals = {}

        for item in self.array:
            # create oval and get its ID
            item_id = self.canvas.create_oval(item, fill='brown', tags='id')
            # remember ID and its start position
            self.ovals[item_id] = item

        self.canvas.tag_bind('id', '<ButtonPress-1>', self.start_move)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('id', '<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('id', '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.stop_move)

        # to remember selected item
        self.selected = None

    def start_move(self, event):
        # find all clicked items
        self.selected = self.canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y)
        # get first selected item
        self.selected = self.selected[0]

    def move(self, event):
        # move selected item
        self.canvas.coords(self.selected, event.x-10, event.y-10, event.x+10,event.y+10)

    def stop_move(self, event):
        # delete or release selected item
        if 100 < event.x < 300 and 250 < event.y < 350:
            self.canvas.delete(self.selected)
            del self.ovals[self.selected]
        else:
            self.canvas.coords(self.selected, self.ovals[self.selected])
        # clear it so you can use it to check if you are draging item
        self.selected = None

root = tk.Tk()
d = Desktop(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** using `event.widget.find_withtag("current")[0]` I can get first selected item, and I can skip `<ButtonPress-1>`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Desktop:

    array = [(50,50,70,70),(100,50,120,70),(150,50,170,70),(150,100,170,120),
            (150,150,170,170),(100,150,120,170),(50,150,70,170),(50,100,70,120)]

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 250, 300, 350)

        # to keep all IDs and its start position
        self.ovals = {}

        for item in self.array:
            # create oval and get its ID
            item_id = self.canvas.create_oval(item, fill='brown', tags='id')
            # remember ID and its start position
            self.ovals[item_id] = item

        self.canvas.tag_bind('id', '<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('id', '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.stop_move)

    def move(self, event):
        # get selected item
        selected = event.widget.find_withtag("current")[0]

        # move selected item
        self.canvas.coords(selected, event.x-10, event.y-10, event.x+10,event.y+10)

    def stop_move(self, event):
        # get selected item
        selected = event.widget.find_withtag("current")[0]

        # delete or release selected item
        if 100 < event.x < 300 and 250 < event.y < 350:
            self.canvas.delete(selected)
            del self.ovals[selected]
        else:
            self.canvas.coords(selected, self.ovals[selected])

root = tk.Tk()
d = Desktop(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** added `del self.ovals[selected]`

Comment: nice solution. is there other way to get the oval to be moved except finding the overlapping one?

Comment: `event` doesn't give item ID . You could bind method to every item separately and  then you could add ID as argument.

Comment: using Google I found that you can use `self.selected = event.widget.find_withtag("current")[0]` to get first selected ID because `event.widget` gives access to canvas